# Comparing a string outside a loop with one outside the loop in java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, compare

I am working on writing a program that takes a word from the user like "banana" takes the first letter of the word "b" puts it at the end like ananab then checks to see if it spells the same word. I have been working on this for a couple days and have tried several things but still unsure about how to check a string given by the user with one inside a for loop. This is my program so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter words that can be checked for backward spelling");
    System.out.println("Please enter a word to check");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String words = keyboard.nextLine();
    String firstLetter = String.valueOf(words.charAt(0));
    String words2 = words.substring(1);
    String otherwords = words2+firstLetter;


    for (int i=otherwords.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        String newwords=String.valueOf(otherwords.charAt(i));
        boolean match = newwords.equalsIgnoreCase(words);
        if (match){
            System.out.println("This word matches the criteria we are lookin for");}
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String []args){

String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

char addToEnd = input.charAt(0);
String newString = input.substring(1);
newString+=addToEnd;

if(input.equals(newString)){
System.out.println("This is a match");

}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you...I added the loop because I needed to reverse the the string once I added the letter at the end otherwise it would not be the same word. It would be ananab instead of banana Is there an alternative way to reverse a string without a loop, I previously tried String buffer I might have to use that again?

Comment: There is no need to reverse the string back. We never lost it. If the user enters "banana", then the String input would be "banana", and the String newString would be "ananab". After the if statement, we still have the String input...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter words that can be checked for backward spelling");
    System.out.println("Please enter a word to check");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = sc.nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(word.substring(1));
    sb.append(word.charAt(0));
    System.out.println(sb.toString().equals(word)?"This is a match.":"This is not a match.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter words that can be checked for backward spelling");
System.out.println("Please enter a word to check");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = keyboard.nextLine();
keyboard.close();
String firstLetter = word.substring(0, 1);
String newWord = word.substring(1) + firstLetter;
// reverse the word
String reversedWord = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    reversedWord = word.substring(i, i + 1) + reversedWord;
}
// check if it matches
if (reversedWord.equalsIgnoreCase(newWord)) {
    System.out.println("This word matches the criteria we are looking for!!!");
}
```

Comment: Drogba, thank you this is excellent, I am going to read through the lines and practice with something else so I understand!!!